# sudzc or wsdl2obj?

Tags: iphone, cocoa, parsing, wsdl

I know this question has been asked several times but the issue here is a little different.

In order for iphone to consume the WSDL, i tried to use wsdl2obj for but got the error as UNSINGED BYTE... during compilation and no help found on this over the internet.

Now when i try using the sudcz wsdl convertor, I am able to parse the wsdl and get the resulting XML but unfortunately, unable to get the rest as sudcz does classes dont read my xml property to generate proper objects.

Any help here?

Regards, 
Accilies

Answer (score 0):

I had some of the same problems.  I had to setup structures in the web service and used these to return the data from the web service call.  I was able to easily parse the returned XML.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Sean, I am now using sudzc to parse WSDL. Thanks for the reply !

Comment: Are there any alternatives? Because i got a crash with the two of them.